# How do I provide an input string to jsonpath?

Tags: python, jsonpath

I am trying to use [jsonpath-rw](https://github.com/kennknowles/python-jsonpath-rw) to get JSON values however when I try to:

```
input_string = "{'foo': [{'baz': 1}, {'baz': 2}]}"
result = [match.value for match in jsonpath_ex.find(input_string)]
print result 
[]
```

the result is always an empty list. However when I use the following code I get a result:

```
result = [match.value for match in jsonpath_ex.find(ast.literal_eval(input_string))]
print result 
[1, 2]
```

which is better than the first output. When `input_string = """{'foo': [{'baz': true}, {'baz': 2}]}"""` which is valid JSON but not valid Python I get:

```
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
```

However when `true` is in double quotes parsing succeeds. How do I provide `input_string` such that `jsonpath-rw` can find over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use a string as input for `jsonpath_ex.find(input)` use the `json` module to parse the input string, this will convert it to a Python object. For example:

```
result_list = [match.value for match in jsonpath_ex.find(json.loads(input_string))]
```